# toggling between two functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I intend to toggle between the two functions by having another button which would set the value of trigger to be 1 and let the second function run. But it doesn't seem to be working. What is the solution to this?

```
<input type="button" value="Intersection Nodes" id="intersection" onclick="triggerbutton();">

var trigger=0;

function triggerbutton(){
       trigger=1;
}

node.on("click", function() { 
                if(trigger==0){
                    clickNode;
                }
                if(trigger==1){
                    clickNodeSpecial;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with d3.js, but this is how I would do it with jQuery/javascript:

#### jsfiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/joelns/bh1b40vb/3/

#### html

```
<button href='#' id='click_me'>Toggle Me</button>
```

#### javascript

```
var toggleDemo=function(){
var status=true;    
jQuery('#click_me').click(function() {

    onOff($(this));


    });

function onOff(el){
             /*
             * toggle
             */
            status = (status ? false : true);

            status
                    ? el.html('on')
                    : el.html('off');
}
}

toggleDemo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with jPepper or with your preferred library:

```
var trigger = 0;

_("#tb").on("click", function(e) {
    trigger = trigger == 0 ? 1 : 0;
});

_("#nb").on("click", function(e) {
    if (trigger == 0) 
        alert("trigger is 0");
    else
        alert("trigger is 1");        
});
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6wrE/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use jQuery to bind a click event to your node, simply bind another click event to your button via jQuery as well.

```
var trigger = 0;

$('#intersection').click(function(){
    trigger = 1;
});

$(node).click(function(){
    if( trigger ) {    
        //trigger = 1 function
    } else {    
        //trigger = 0 function    
    }
});
```